# Grab current facebook ID on first call

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Android version of the facebook graph-API. And to handle login, we do a simple authorize dialog, which will call the onComplete if everything works fine. However the problem is that I need the user ID, so I need to make a sequential `facebook.request("me")` to grab that. Is there a way to get the user ID in the authorization logic?? The bundle values only return the acess_token and expire_time

```
facebook.authorize(this, permissions, new DialogListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            login();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {}

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {}
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after some googling I found some info about the access_token. One cool part is that it contains a substring that identify the user ID. The access token have this format:

```
116122545078207|2.1vGZASUSFMHeMVgQ_9P60Q__.3600.1272535200-500880518|QXlU1XfJR1mMagHLPtaMjJzFZp4.
```

The part that identify the User ID is from the second `|` to the first left `-`, so the user ID of the access token above is: `500880518`

To grab it, just do:

```
public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
    String token = values.getString("access_token");
    String[] firstPart = token.split("\\|");
    String[] subPart = firstPart[1].split("-");
    long id = Long.parseLong(subPart[subPart.length - 1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply no... you have to call user/me for that. but you can have it sequentialy after the authorize complete call because in order to get any kind of info from facebook that is not public you need the token and authorize just returns authentication info. what you are asking is like wanting to get the friend list by calling for a wall post.. the calls aren't interconnected.